# How to wrap nicely using css columns in a horizontal scrolling layout

Tags: css, multiple-columns, horizontal-scrolling, word-wrap, column-width

I am stuck on a problem: I have a horizontally scrolling layout (no vertical scroll), where I want to lay out text content in columns. Since I don't know how long the text will be, I want all the available text to be filled up in columns according to the available space (column width can be fixed, max height is the viewport height).

See the problem illustrated here (resize to see how text flows): https://ldaniel.eu/_/fj-test/text-test.html

Thought I could use CSS columns for it — including `column-fill: auto;` to let text fill up from left to right instead of evenyl distribute — but it seems that the containing div always tries to fill up the remaining space, even if set to `inline-block` or `flex`.

I have been breaking my neck over this problem for a while now, talked about it with some people, but nobody seems to have a solution... is this a limitation of the CSS spec to only work with vertical layouts? Or is it a limitation of my brain to want to solve this with only CSS and leave JS out of it? :)

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.test-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.block__text {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  column-width: 200px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
}

.block__text p {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-wrapper">

  <div class="block">

    <div class="block__text">

      <h2>How I work</h2>

      <p>I work by harnessing the intimate power of words, guiding you through face-to-face, hour-long interviews during which we will detail and dissect your projects, your ambitions, and the obstructions you might be facing. These consultations will occasionally
        alternate with more active exercises designed to restore the natural connection between thoughts and feelings.</p>

      <p>While it may feel at first like we are merely chatting, we will be using your own words and actions as leverage to tap the power of your unconscious mind...</p>

    </div>

    <div class="block__image">
      <img src="http://wiki.apidesign.org/images/8/82/HtmlForFood.png" alt="" />
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="block">

    <div class="block__text">

      <h2>Giftedness</h2>

      <p>Gifted and talented adults face unique challenges made all the more pressing by the normative demands of contemporary life. While their highly functional intellect enables them to conform outwardly to social and professional expectations, these
        coping mechanisms often come at a high personal cost, resulting in silent suffering and the loss of tremendous creative potential.</p>

      <p>Giftedness is not solely about IQ, nor is it a badge of honour to be worn in public. In fact, many gifted adults have never undergone an IQ test, nor do they have any reason to. It is, rather, a way of relating to the world, a way that is rich,
        layered, intense, and all-too-often coloured by inner conflicts and a distressing surfeit of information. Giftedness can be both a blessing and a curse: only you can decide.</p>

      <p>The joys and pains of gifted individuals have been a particular study of mine ever since I witnessed at first hand what suffering and loneliness these exceptional adults could experience. Today, I am privileged to work with these talented minds
        as they unlock their full potential in fields as diverse as technology, marketing, politics, and the arts (If my name rings a bell, it might be because my mother literally wrote the book on giftedness). The diversity and intensity of their achievements
        never fails to humble and inspire me.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="block__image">
      <img src="http://wiki.apidesign.org/images/8/82/HtmlForFood.png" alt="" />
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you create a demo of the code you're working with, and ideally an image of the desired layout? Thanks

Comment: A demo is viewable at the link above (https://ldaniel.eu/_/fj-test/text-test.html)

... and you can see the intended behaviour here: https://twitter.com/ldanielswakman/status/953225103017435136

Comment: @LDanielSwakman What sol means is, to create a similar demo in a snippet, so we can see the code what you did till this moment, and maybe how to solve it...

Comment: @sol done — made a code snippet